# Prove/disprove that the set is open or closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-writing, metric-spaces

Have a set, $X=\left\{\left(\frac{1}{k}cosk,\frac{1}{k}sink\right):\:k\ge 1\right\}$. It is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Prove or disprove that $X$ is an open set. Prove or disprove that $X$ is a closed set.
Then, determine $Int(X)$ and $Cl(X)$.

---

This is a practice question. There are many practice ones given like this, and I'm trying to figure out how to approach and solve this type of problem.

I have the definitions that I try to start with:

A set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open if $\forall x\in X, \exists\:r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq\:X$.

A set $X\subseteq\:\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed if $X^C$ is open. $\:\:$ ($X^c$ is complement of $X$).

A set $X\subseteq\:\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed iff every sequence in $X$ that converges (to some element $\mathbb{R}^n$) has its limit in $X$.

Here are the approaches I have been thinking about for open:

let $x$ be a point in the set, and then show that there's a ball centered around it that is entirely within the set. Or given $x$ an element of the set, I need to figure out how small the radius must be of the ball around $x$ so that the ball lies within the bounds.

For closed, to prove it I need to show the complement is open. But, I know that a set doesn't need to be open or closed, and a set can be both open and closed, so maybe it's best I don't use an argument of “suppose the set is not open." Otherwise, I can show that the set contains all its limit points: so for some $x$, the limit of $x$ will be contained in $X$.

Comment: And so … is it open?

Comment: @TedShifrin i think it is

Comment: $k$ is a positive integer, right?

Comment: @TedShifrin yes $k$ is a positive integer. I think it's open since $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{x}sinx\right)=$ and $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{x}cosx\right)=0$, but $0$ is not in the set since $k>0$. I think it's open since all the interior points of $X$ are interior point of $X$. Am I thinking about this correctly? I know it's not by the definition but I'm struggling with that. I think with the set, you can keep making small balls with small radius closer and closer to the edges of the set, but I'm not quite sure what the edges are

Comment: No, you’re not thinking right. The set is open if and only if you can wiggle every point in it and stay within the set. Taking limits probably has more to do with closedness.

Comment: @TedShifrin oh okay, so for $X$ to be open, every possible $x$ for any positive $k$ value, an entire open ball around $x$ must be within the set of $X$ right? And the set of $X$ is bounded by $(0,\infty)$ since $\infty>cosk/k>0$ and $\infty>sink/k>0$? So the interval I need to look at is $(0,\infty)$ which is open?

Comment: No, for every $x$ in the set, an entire open ball around $x$ must be contained in the set.

Comment: @TedShifrin now i'm thinking it's not open or closed. Not closed since it does not contain all it's limit points, namely $(x,y)=(0,0)$ which is not contained in the set $X$. And I think it's not open since for $k=1$, have that $(x,y)= (cos(1),sin(1))$, but there is no ball that can be made around it with $r>0$...is this better?

Comment: Yes, much better! Keep learning.

Comment: @TedShifrin YAYYY :) thanks for the hints!! Is my justification for not open good enough or am I still missing something?

Comment: It’s true for every $k$, but in fact you must write better and more explicit mathematical sentences.

Comment: @TedShifrin would it work if I say that it $X$ is not open because if we take any $k$, particularly $k=1$, we get $(cos(1),sin(1))$, which is the minimum value of the set. So, there is no ball of radius $r$ around the point where $(r-(cos1,sin1),r+(cos1,sin1))$ is also contained in $X$ for any small $r$.

Comment: There is no ordering on the plane, so “minimum value” makes no sense. Have you drawn a picture of the set $X$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I did try to draw a picture on $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane, and  I basically have a bunch of points close to the origin, but not touching it. I wasn't sure if the picture was right or how to interpret it properly. I'm thinking that each point in $X$ is an isolated point of $X$ since it has no close neighbors that are also in $X$. So, for some interval $(x-c,x+c)$, $(x-c,x+c)∩X=\{x\}$ And since all the points are isolated, it does not have interior points,....,so it's open. Is this correct?

Comment: NO. You need to reread and reread and *understand* the definitions. It wouldn't hurt to reread my comments to you, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $x_n\rightarrow O$ converges to the origin $O=(0,0)$ which does not belong to the set $X$. By your third definition this means that $X$ is not closed.

On the other hand, a sequence $y_n=(1+\frac{1}{n},0)$ is contained in $X^c$ (notice $|x_n|\le 1$, while $|y_n|>1$). Yet, $y_n\rightarrow x_1$, which means $X^c$ is not closed, so $X$ is not open.

So, $X$ is neither open nor closed.

Comment: i don't completely understand how $X$ is not open (sorry I'm new to this stuff)

Comment: Did you show that the complement is not closed, which implies that the set is not open? is this a proof by some contrapositive or converse? I'm a bit lost with how it works

Comment: @eddie . Some texts define open and closed in ways that do not make it obvious that a set is open iff its complement is closed.

Comment: @eddie, yes your summary is exactly right. $X$ is open implies $X^c$ is closed (by def.); then since $X^c$ is not closed we get that $X$ is not open (by contrapositive).

Comment: @aninstance would it work if I say that it $X$ is not open because if we take $k=1$, we get $(cos(1),sin(1))$, which is the minimum value of the set. So, there is no ball of radius $r$ around the point where $(r-(cos1,sin1),r+(cos1,sin1))$ is also contained in $X$ for any small $r$

Comment: @eddie you can show that there is no ball around $(cos1, sin1)$ which is entirely contained in $X$ (it's very similar to what I did in the answer). So I think I agree with your question. But I do not understand your notation, it looks like you are adding vectors ($(cos1, sin1)$) and scalars $r$.

Comment: I'm trying to come up with my own examples of a sequence like you did, any pointers on how I can do that?

Comment: $y_n=(1,1/n)$ work?

Comment: yes, that would also work

Comment: I'm trying to work out $Int(X)$ and $Cl(X)$. For $Int(X)$, I think it's empty, but $Cl(X)$, I'm not completely sure. $Cl(X)=Int(X)∪∂(X)$, so $Cl(X)= ∂(X)$ since $Int(X)$ empty, and boundry of $X$ is just $∂(X)=(cosk/k,sink/k)$. Is this right?